# Z-Fighting coplanar faces. Draw one after another

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader

I am trying to simulate Shaded-Wireframe rendering of scene-view in game-view with MeshTopology.Lines.
Currently, object is copied and located at the exact location as original one, then MeshTopology applied.

Only problem i have is that there are visible flickering of lines because of faces overlapping each other. Solution is, for now, to use shader which extrudes vertex along normals. 
But i would like to know if there any way to have two objects with overlapping faces being rendered one after another without flickering.

So far i have used -

RenderQueue is not working for lines, with faces they are working perfectly.

ZTest, Offset with no luck. Even though it works with faces, they do not work with lines generated by MeshTopology. Offset is not working at all, ZTest - can`t find suitable one. if set to Greater(GEqual) lines become visible above anything, Less on original object is not chaning anything.
Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

[Image of line flickering](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XPSIW.png)

Since the final purpose is different from just showing wireframe, i must use MeshTopology. GLlines are too slow.

Comment: The only solution is to offset the duplicated mesh's vertices slightly.

Answer (score 0):

With your use case, and provided that your Z-buffer has enough precision (check near/far planes settings of the camera if needed), you should be able to solve this with just **ZTest**.

In your wireframe shader use `ZTest Equal` and make sure it's drawn after your main mesh using the render queue `Tags { "Queue" = "Geometry+1" }`.

This way the mesh's solid pass will fill the Z-Buffer with it's current depth, and the second - wireframe - pass will be drawn in its place only if the new depth value matches, which it should.